# get YouTube subscribers without youtube api

Tags: java, youtube

Is there a way to get the youtube subscriber count of a certain YouTube Channel without using the youtube api?

I spent some time researching and found this:

https://www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed?channelid=UCopSjr1a2QgRvm-yJRqcPpA

It is a link where you can see the subscriber count of a YouTube Channel via the channel id.

But the problem with this link is that when I look at the subscriber count of bigger YouTube Channels it will just show for example 1M:

https://www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed?channelid=UCppK6hGo5L-dmrryG5T0K0Q

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to use the youtube api? Since the precise data would only be present with youtube/google, I dont think you'll be able to get the precise count elsewhere, unless you scrape the data every second or something yourself.

Comment: Of course because it would be easier without including it and Google sometimes has a lot of bugs in their apis. Also it of course need some storage...

Comment: Ok, which api do I have to use then? (Could you maybe give me a link)

Comment: It would not be easy without using Google's APIs, since anybody else providing the data by scraping it off the website would still be not able to provide the same amount of data which the Google APIs provide with consistency and reliability.

Comment: Please check my answer as requested on using Google's API to get the sub count.

Answer (score 0):

As asked by you in your comment, you may use the below Google API (GET request) to get the subscribers count:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=ABCD&key=XXXXX
```

where `id` is the channel ID and `key`is the auth token.

The sample response would be like below:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "XXX",
 "pageInfo": {
   "totalResults": 1,
   "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
   {
     "kind": "youtube#channel",
     "etag": "XXX",
     "id": "ABCD",
     "statistics": {
       "viewCount": "1197147852",
       "commentCount": "0",
       "subscriberCount": "8042359",
       "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
       "videoCount": "1092"
     }
   }
 ]
```

}

You may find more details on using the APIs and trying them out [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)